# Windows phone is not showing fontweight to Light on device

Tags: xaml, fonts, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to add fontWeight="Light" in my windows phone app. but it is not working on designer it shows light font on emulator or device it does not make font thiner at all.

```
 <TextBlock Text="Some text in normal" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Normal" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some text in normal" FontSize="22"   FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" />
```

here is how it looks on device.
[image]

Here is how it looks in VS designer.

[image]

What I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change font family from `Segoe UI` to `Segoe WP`.

Comment: But I want Segoe UI font

Comment: I think Windows Phone just doesn't have this font. Why you need Segoe UI? Segoe WP look almost the same but is optimized for Windows Phone device.